# After updating i couldn't hear the sound

Tags: sound

I actually updated my ubuntu 12.04 lts after updating all the updates I restarted my system but i can't hear the sound in speaker but i could hear it through headset. could anyone help me to sort this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone into the Sound settings and ensured that the correct output is selected.  Go to "Dash" and search for "Sound."  In the list items try each one while sound is playing.  Or you can also use the "test sound" button as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried ,but it didn't work .

Comment: Does your audio device show up in the list?  I am in need of more details if you need informed responsive answers

Comment: I went into the sound settings ->output ->analog output build -in audio and I adjusted the output volume to maximum . I also tried "test sound" button as well , but I couldn't hear any sound from my laptop but when I connected the headset I could  hear the sound clearly .@dylan